# Unable to connect to deployed Azure Cloud service

Tags: azure, tcp

I've been unable to connect to my Azure Cloud service once I deploy it.  Looking at the answers to similar questions, I've tried examining my endpoints, but they seem to be configured correctly.  I'm trying to connect through TCP.  Everything runs fine locally, when I use the Azure Compute Emulator.

Here's my .csdef file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ServiceDefinition name="Server"     xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ServiceHosting/2008/10/ServiceDefinition"     schemaVersion="2013-03.2.0">
  <WorkerRole name="WorkerRole" vmsize="Small">
    <Imports>
      <Import moduleName="Diagnostics" />
    </Imports>
    <Endpoints>
      <InputEndpoint name="Endpoint1" protocol="tcp" port="4029"/>
    </Endpoints>
    <LocalResources>
      <LocalStorage name="DiagnosticStore" sizeInMB="20000" cleanOnRoleRecycle="false" />
    </LocalResources>
  </WorkerRole>
</ServiceDefinition>
```

On my server instance, which is an Azure worker role, I have the following TCP Listener:

```
const int port = 4029;
IPAddress addr = IPAddress.Loopback;
try
{
    var listener = new TcpListener(addr, port);
    listener.Start();
    ...
}
```

And finally, in my client I have the following:

```
var hostName = new HostName("[IP Address as shown in the Azure Management Portal]");
TcpSocket = new StreamSocket();

try
{
     await TcpSocket.ConnectAsync(hostName, "4029");
     ...
}
```

This code works fine and I'm able to connect my client to my server when my server is running locally in the Azure emulator, so I'm inclined to think that the problem lies in the way I've set up my server on Azure.  Are there any additional things I should check for, or tips on how to further debug this?  Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect the problem is your use of IPAddress.Loopback and the choice of local port.

Since you don't specify a local port in the [ServiceDefinition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg433020.aspx) configuration for the endpoint Windows Azure could assign a random port. You should then access the endpoint using:

```
listener = new TcpListener( 
    RoleEnvironment.CurrentRoleInstance.InstanceEndpoints["Endpoint1"].IPEndpoint); 
listener.ExclusiveAddressUse = false; 
listener.Start();
```

This code comes from a Maarten Balliauw [post](http://blog.maartenballiauw.be/post/2010/01/17/Creating-an-external-facing-Azure-Worker-Role-endpoint.aspx).

You can optionally specify the local port in the Service Definition file.